# lodash Mongoose object id difference

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, lodash

I have two arrays of mongoose `Object` ids and I want to get the difference of these two sets. I am using lodash. My ObjectId array is as follows.

```
    let a = [ 59dba788b6068c16ca0b5aa6,
  59dba88bb6068c16ca0b5aa8,
  59dba973b6068c16ca0b5aaa,
  59dba973b6068c16ca0b5aab,
  59dbaa0db6068c16ca0b5aad,
  59dbaa0db6068c16ca0b5aae,
  59dce08e996af20b6a6ceea4,
  59e05048739e3d192b64d3cf,
  59e05048739e3d192b64d3d0 ];

  let b= [ 59dba788b6068c16ca0b5aa6,
   59dba88bb6068c16ca0b5aa8,
   59e05048739e3d192b64d3d0,
   59dba973b6068c16ca0b5aaa ];



  console.log(_.difference(allStudentsArrray, presentStudentsArray));
```

& it prints all the elements in a

Comment: This site works best if you describe your problem and show how you have tried to solve it, along with the problem you encountered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `_.difference` use `_.differenceWith`  with `_.isEqual` argument like as follows

```
console.log(_.differenceWith(allStudentsArrray, presentStudentsArray,_.isEqual));
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

The **_.isEmpty()** function from lodash returns true if the provided value is considered "empty". For an ObjectID, even if it's not null or undefined, it might still be considered "empty" if lodash's internal logic doesn't recognize it.

In such cases, you might want to check specifically for null or undefined as follows:

```
if (ObjectId === null || ObjectId === undefined) {
// branchData._id is null or undefined
}
```

instead of

```
   if (_.isEmpty(ObjectId)){

   }
```